# Docker `docker pull` works only locally?

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I just downloaded Docker and started with following command:

`docker pull ubuntu`

and get the following reply:

```
Pulling repository ubuntu
2015/06/28 19:03:47 Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/ubuntu/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on [127.0.1.1]:53: no such host
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: it looks like maybe you don't have dns?  can you do 'ping index.docker.io'?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can't ping that url!!

Comment: Do you know how to configure the DNS?

Comment: that depends on your operating system.  is it unix? /etc/resolv.conf, add a line nameserver 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have a problem in the network, the wireless connection was not stable. Thank you for your concern!